# What is this error message, and how do I resolve it?

Tags: python, syntax-error, stdin

I'm taking [google's python tutorial](https://developers.google.com/edu/python) and may have fat fingered a few keys, causing an error. I don't recognize the issue here, and the ctrl+click links it allows me to follow take me to line 1 of the file I'm writing in and to python.exe.

It looks like there's an extra character somewhere in a file path? There are no syntax errors in the code itself as the debugger runs through it just fine.

I'm using Visual Studio Code

None of the code I've written (with my knowledge) is causing this error.

This is the error message I'm getting.

```py
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> & C:/Users/mcgilm1/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/python.exe c:/Users/mcgilm1/Documents/google-python-exercises/basic/string2.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    & C:/Users/mcgilm1/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/python.exe c:/Users/mcgilm1/Documents/google-python-exercises/basic/string2.py
    ^
```

Comment: Can you include your code?

Comment: Aside from the `&`, you appear to be trying to type a shell/interpreter command directly in the Python interpreter itself.

Answer (score 0):

Including your code could help us, here is a list of things to check that I found on the web: [Debugging](http://www.openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english2e/app_a.html)

Make sure you are not using a Python keyword for a variable name.
Check that you have a colon at the end of the header of every compound statement, including for, while, if, and def statements.

Check that indentation is consistent. You may indent with either spaces or tabs but it’s best not to mix them. Each level should be nested the same amount.
Make sure that any strings in the code have matching quotation marks.

If you have multiline strings with triple quotes (single or double), make sure you have terminated the string properly. An unterminated string may cause an invalid token error at the end of your program, or it may treat the following part of the program as a string until it comes to the next string. In the second case, it might not produce an error message at all!

An unclosed bracket – (, {, or [ – makes Python continue with the next line as part of the current statement. Generally, an error occurs almost immediately in the next line.

Check for the classic = instead of == inside a conditional.